# Sql more than 2 is note null

Tags: python, sql, web2py

I have got table with some colums like: `colum_1, colum_2, colum_3...`

I need to select from this table only rows with 2 or more `colum_` that is not null

Comment: the only method I have is write all the combinations: WHERE (column_1 IS NOT NULL AND column_2 IS NOT NULL) OR (column_2 IS NOT NULL AND column_3 IS NOT NULL) OR ...    but it depends on the number of columns of your table

Comment: I have got a lot of colums(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the web2py database abstraction layer:

```
template = '(case when %s is not null then 1 else 0 end)'
query = '(%s) > 2' % reduce(lambda a, b: '%s + %s' % (a, b),
                            [template % f for f in db.mytable])
rows = db(query).select(db.mytable.ALL)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `where` clause, but it is a bit complicated:

```
where ((case when column_1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when column_2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
       . . .
       (case when column_n is not null then 1 else 0 end)
      ) >= 2
```